# MVC- report show redundant values

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, report, reporting

I've an web app using MVC ,
it views a report from "View " 
Vtasks View :

```
 SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tasks.task_id, dbo.tasks.task_name, dbo.tasks.task_desc, dbo.tasks.date, dbo.tasks.notes, dbo.employees.emp_name, dbo.status.state_name, dbo.users.username
FROM            dbo.departments INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tasks ON dbo.departments.dep_id = dbo.tasks.dep INNER JOIN
                         dbo.status ON dbo.tasks.state = dbo.status.state_Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.users ON dbo.tasks.created_by = dbo.users.id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.emp_task ON dbo.tasks.task_id = dbo.emp_task.task_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.employees ON dbo.emp_task.emp_id = dbo.employees.id
ORDER BY dbo.tasks.task_id
```

**report controller:**

```
      var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();

 reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"Reports\tasksRep1.rdlc";

            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", db.Vtasks.ToList()));
            reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
            reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
            reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;

            ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
```

report viewer:

```
 @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

**selection result from sql server :** 
[image]

**selection result from reportviewer**
[image]

the problem is the report shows redundant emp_name for the same task_name .

I don't know what's the problem ,I appreciate any help 
thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are running both against the same instance? Also, be aware that TOP 100% and the subsequent order by are usually optimised away, and this does absolutely nothing to influence the order of the view ([simple demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2fac7e4937ccdac28ffef2a6dda0b0f)). If you care about the order of something, specify it each and every time, e.g. `db.Vtasks.OrderBy(v => v.task_id).ToList()`

Comment: Repeat after me - TOP (100) PERCENT does nothing useful. Learn that! You are only fooling yourself and the engine syntax checker when using this in the creation of a view. If you want an ordered resultset, the query generating that resultset must include an order by clause. Do not be mislead by any pattern you might see using small sets of data or lightly used servers.

Comment: And "redundant" data implies that there is either a schema flaw or a logical flaw in the query. The only way to figure this out is to include all the primary keys from the tables referenced in the query and all the columns used to join. Run the query in SSMS query window and debug it there first.

Comment: removing the existing dataset and adding another one solved the problem 
thanks @GarethD

Comment: I added a new dataset with all pk and the problem solved , thanks @SMor